# Как узнать id категории? (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Как узнать id категории по её названию, например: категория называеться "Основное" и надо чтоб после того как категория создалась в переменную osnid записывалось id этого канала чтоб потом создать в ней чат, пробовал по названию категории пишет нужно id, создавал так:

```
await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"правила",overwrites=None, category="Основеное", reason=None)
```

но выдало ошибку что должен быть атрибут id я попытался сделать OSNid = id(input ("::: ")) после создания категории, от пользователя требовалось ввести id категории, и в команду для создания текстового канала вводилось вместо названия OSNid, но и так не вышло писало что атребут str а надо id

код:

```
@bot.command()
async def uncrash(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author

    await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    OSNid = int(input ("::: "))
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST1", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST2", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST3", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST4", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST5", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST6", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST7", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST8", overwrites=None,category=f"{OSNid}", reason=None)
```

Comment: `await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST1", overwrites=None,category_id=OSNid, reason=None)`? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.category_id

Comment: @gil9red нет в таком случае TEST1 создаеться не в категории, и все же надо вводить id категории что очень не удобно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[create_category](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_category) вернет [CategoryChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel) который имеет метод для создания текстовых каналов.

```
category = await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", overwrites=None, reason=None)
await category.create_text_channel(f"TEST1", overwrites=None, reason=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

А так?

```
@bot.command()
async def uncrash(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author

    category = await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f"TEST1", overwrites=None, category=category, reason=None)
```

Comment: нет, так это не работает

Comment: @Selasi, какие там ошибки?

Comment: не найденна категория "category"

Comment: Странная категория, ведь по вашему коду вы создавали категорию TEST